# -webkit-text-stroke chrome multiple lines

Tags: css, google-chrome, text, fonts, webkit

I am trying to use -webkit-text-stroke to create an outline on a text. It seems to work fine in Safari. However, when I look in chrome it renders the font with multiple lines. The only way it doesn't do this is if I use an .eot font however it is not very well supported. I have tried all other fonts woff woff2 otf tff.

Is there anyway to fix this? Or, what could possibly be the issue?

Here is the css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Platform-Medium';
    src: url(../assets/Platform-Medium.otf);
    font-weight: 500;
}


body{
    font-family: 'Apercu', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 2;
    /* here we smoothed the text a touch */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.platform-medium {
    font-family: 'Platform-Medium';
}


.f7 {
    font-size: 13rem;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
}

.light{
    color:#E8EFEE;
}

.text-outline{
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #E8EFEE;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

I should also mention that I am using Tachyons.

```html
<section class="hero min-vh-100 cover bg-center flex items-center justify-center" style="<?php if( get_field('hero_image') ):?> 
 background-image: url(<?php the_field('hero_image'); ?>;<?php endif; ?>">
  
  <div class="hero-content flex items-center justify-center w-100">

   <!-- If no image is added to the 'subhead' 
   custom field then the title of the post will be chown -->
   <?php if( get_field( 'Subhead' ) ): ?>
    <img class="subhead w-75" src="<?php the_field('Subhead'); ?>" />
               <?php else: ?>
               <h1 class="light platform-medium f7 ma0 text-outline ttu tc"><?php the_title();?></h1>
               <?php endif; ?>    

  </div>

 </section>
```

This is the result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaHtB.jpg)

Comment: I think you need to show us more code here. When I use your code in Chrome, it renders as expected. https://codepen.io/kerri9494/pen/mveqYj

Comment: Hi Kerri, I have added some more code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since we don't have access to your server, and can't run your PHP, unfortunately I'm still not able to reproduce this. (It's really important to include code that anyone else could run and show what the error looks like. Screen shots are helpful, but they don't tell the story of 'why'.) If you have a live URL on a server that's demonstrating this behavior, and can share it here, that is helpful. You can even view the source of your page and save it somewhere else such as an other web page, or a CodePen or JSFiddle.